# How to load a new external HTML for each event?

Tags: ajax, vuetify.js

- *Problem*: I want to show an `v-html`   into the *modal* interface, and the content comes from an URL (ajax)... The snipped code is running, but it is bad, not professional: try to run. You  click *GO*, take a message saying to *CLOSE* and click *GO* again... 
  I need to "[promisify](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30008114/287948) my code" with Vue's best practices.

**Question**: how to do this interface better, all with Vuetify?

I need one-click (*GO*) interface, and with mininal waiting time for user.

(need also to load other URLs, so using AJAX many times as other buttons, etc.)

I am supposing that Vuetify have good approaches to AJAX-load (as [these](https://vuejsdevelopers.com/2017/08/28/vue-js-ajax-recipes/)), so I need to use the best one! for this situation.

PS: I not see how to implement the Vue-AJAX strategies in a single HTML page (not a big Node.js system).

### A simplified ugly-interface example

It is running, but is mixing non-VueJS code and have all the explained problems, to be fixed by the answer.

```js
var URL = 'https://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/difoC.html';    
var loadFromUrl_cache = '... PLEASE WAYTE 10 seconds ...'+
    '<br/>close and back here.';

function loadFromUrl(URL,tmpStore) {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
           if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
               loadFromUrl_cache = xmlhttp.responseText;
           } else {
               alert('ERROR, something else other than status 200:'+
               xmlhttp.status);
           }
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", URL, true); // async
    xmlhttp.send();
}

// to get rid of "missing v-app" error message
var app = document.createElement('div');
app.setAttribute('data-app', true);
document.body.appendChild(app);

let mainVue = new Vue({ el: '#main' });

new Vue({
  el: '#appDlg',
  data() {
    return {
      dialog: false,
      ct_header: 'the header1 here',
      ct_body: 'the body1 here'
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    mainVue.$on('go-modal', this.handleMain);
  },
  methods: {
    handleMain(data) {
      this.ct_header = data.title;
      loadFromUrl(URL,'tmp-store');
      this.ct_body = loadFromUrl_cache;
      this.dialog = true;
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.myDialog { 
  padding: 10px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: white; 
}

.myDialog .btn { margin: 20px 0 0 -4px; }
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@0.14.8/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.2/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@0.14.8/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700|Material+Icons' rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<div id="main">
  <v-expansion-panel>
    <v-btn @click="$emit('go-modal', {title: 'Hello', body: 'Bye!'})">Go</v-btn>
  </v-expansion-panel>
</div>

<div id="appDlg">
  <v-dialog v-model="dialog" fullscreen>
    <div class="myDialog">
      <v-btn @click="dialog = false">Close</v-btn>
      <h4>{{ ct_header }}</h4>
      <div v-html="ct_body"></div>
      <v-btn @click="dialog = false">Close</v-btn>
    </div>
  </v-dialog>
</div>
```

---

PS:   thanks to the [code at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49309307/287948). If you prefer you can use [codepen/NYRGyv](https://codepen.io/ppKrauss/pen/NYRGyv).

Comment: what do you mean by "ugly"? You don't have any css afaics.

Comment: Hi @Traxo, sorry, I edited, it is "not professional" ;-)   need more friendly and elegant interface. Not 3 clicks (GO/CLOSE/GO), only one click (GO). And need all as Vue code, my `loadFromUrl()`  is not Vue.js

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I am supposing that Vuetify have good approaches to AJAX-load (as these), so I need to use the best one! for this situation.

You can try [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios)

then you can change for example `ct_body` html like so:

```
handleMain(data) {
    var URL = "your HTML url here";
    axios.get(URL)
    .then(response => {
        this.ct_body = response.data;
    })
}
```

Currently your problem is that you are trying to change html before you even fetch the data.

You should set it after you retrieve it with ajax call.

Note that fetching HTML from url is not instant (tho it should be relatively fast), so depends on your case where you want to put loading indicator. Thus it's up to you where you want to set `this.dialog = true` - inside `.then()` will make it open only when you retrieve html data.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xWRmQG)

Comment: Hi, **axios** is perfect!  Please show the solution running in a fork of https://codepen.io/ppKrauss/pen/NYRGyv   PS: the URL is a global there, you need only to delete my `handleMain()`, my `loadFromUrl()`  and add your 7 lines... And load the axios script.

Comment: @PeterKrauss edited. note that I include it with `script`, but only because its on codepen. read docs on how to install it.

Answer (score 1):

### Pure Javascript (ECMAScript 2015)

We can use `fetch()` and its embedded [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then)! See [developer.mozilla.org/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch).

```
handleMain(data) {
  var self = this;
  self.ct_header = data.title;      
  fetch(URL)
  .then(function(res) { return res.text(); })
  .then(function(data) {
    self.ct_body = data;
    self.dialog = true;
  });
}
```

... Is equivalent to Axios, but, as **it seems exactly the same**, the solution **is better** because avoid to lost of CPU-time, internet-bandwidth and memory (13kb) loading *Axios*. See

https://codepen.io/ppKrauss/pen/oqYOrY

Comment: >"it seems exactly the same", not same, check compatibility for example:   https://caniuse.com/#feat=fetch

So it depends on your needs of course (it's possible that `fetch` is sufficient in your case).

Comment: Hi @Traxo, yes, the eternal problem with MS-IE...  And, of course, when adopting *fetch()*, the older browsers (before 2015) are also excluded. But I, my customers and my community, we are modern and we hate Microsoft, so we can ignore MS-IE :-)